# How to generate XSL HTML table

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I'm trying to create an XSL style sheet that displays value from an XML code into an HTML table. The table headers show in the browser but no values at all.

Can this be an issue stemming from the XSD code associated with it or is it not really relevant. I'm not really sure why the HTML table will not display the information from the XML code.

```js
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"
    xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method = "html" doctype-system = "about:legacy-compat"/>
<xsl:template match = "/">
    <html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta charset = "utf-8"/>        
            <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
            <title> Cookies </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border = "1" syle = "background-color: blue">
                <thead>
                    <tr> 
                        <th> Calories</th>
                        <th> Fat - Calories</th>
                        <th> Fat - Grams </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <xsl:for-each select="/product/item">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="calories/amount"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="caloriesFat/amount"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="gramsFat/amount"/>
                             </td>
                    </tr>                   
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```html
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "nutrition.xsl"?>
<nutrition:items xmlns:nutrition = "http://www.grandmascookies.com/nutrition">
<product name = "Grandma White's Cookies">
<item>
        <servingsize> 
                <amount> 1 </amount> 
                <unit> package </unit> 
                </servingsize>  
        <calories> 
                <amount> 260 </amount> 
                <unit> calories </unit> 
                </calories>
        <caloriesFat> 
                <amount> 100 </amount> 
                <unit> grams </unit> 
                </caloriesFat>  
        <gramsFat> 
                <amount> 11 </amount> 
                <unit> grams </unit> 
                </gramsFat> 
</item>
</product>
</nutrition:items>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in the wrong place. Your xml is /nutrition:items/product/item, not /product/item. Better still, use relative paths from where you are matching so get rid of the initial / which takes you to the root.

In addition, each xsl:value-of should go in its own td tag to match the th tags in your header.

You can debug xsl (in an extremely limited way) by using <xsl:copy-of select='.'/> to see what node is the current one.